# Entry not showig

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
    from tkinter import *


class calc:
    def mult(a,b):
        global result  #Declaration must take place in each function. Else its local
        result = a*b
    def div(a,b):
        global result  #Declaration must take place in each function. Else its local
        result=a*b
    def add(a,b):
        global result  #Declaration must take place in each function. Else its local
        result = a*b
    def sub(a,b):
        global result  #Declaration must take place in each function. Else its local
        result = a*b
#calc.mult(10,5)
#print(result)

window = Tk()
window.title('Calculator')
window.geometry("300x200")
textBox=Entry(window)

mainloop()
formula = textBox.get()
print(formula)
```

I cant seem to get the Entry showing. It does work on my other computer but not here for some reasons, unless i changed something again.

Can you  guys help ?

Comment: Could you please post details about your OS and Python version? as well as the OS and Python version of the computer where the program worked?

Comment: Win10 Python 3.7 Information is irrelevant because i dont see any coordinates for Entry. How does it work, Entry(window,"200x100+10+20") or something ? Where to i tell python the location of the entry i am trying to create ?

Answer (score 0):

For a widget to appear, you have to call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on that widget, or insert it into another widget such as a canvas, text widget, notebook, etc. You aren't calling any of those methods on your entry widget.

Comment: Please give me the simplest example.